# Automatically manage multiple custom scopes for categories in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails 5 and working on a project where in there is a page for each categories and will only show the blog items with specific or same categories.

For instance: Blog Title 1 to Blog Title 5 has a category "Tech" and Blog Title 6 to Blog Title 8 has a category "Business".

If I click on http://localhost:3000/blogs/tech it will show the Blog Title 1 to 5 and if I click on http://localhost:3000/blogs/business it will show the Blog Title 6 to 8.

To do these what I've tried is create custom scope on my blogs controller:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
 def index
    @blogs = Blog.all
  end

  def business
    @blogs = Blog.business
  end 
end
```

And then on my blog model:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord

def self.business
    where(post_category: 1)
 end 

end
```

I also created a new view for my business method to show all the business type category blog items and just copied the same content on my index.html.erb file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Post Category 0</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= blog.title %></td>
        <td><%= blog.body %></td>
        <td><%= link_to blog.status, toggle_status_blog_path(blog) %></td>
        <td><%= blog.post_category.title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', blog %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_blog_path(blog) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', blog, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Blog', new_blog_path %>
```

And finally I updated my routes:

```
  get 'blogs/business', to: 'blogs#business'
```

While this will work for single items. Putting it manually wont work if each time I create a new category plus I don't know exactly what will be the user of the app will add on the category title. How can I do this programmatically so it will create new pages each time a new category is being created instead of adding manually and creating views each time?

Are there any ways to do these?

Side Note: Blog and PostCategory table are related to each each other via post_category_id.

Comment: Please clarify the issue.  'While this will work for single items. Putting it manually wont work if each time I create a new category plus I dont know exactly what will be the user of the app will add on the category title' is a little cryptic.  Are you saying you want to update multiple blogs at once?  what does 'putting it manually' mean?  Less pronouns will help your question be a bit more clear : )

Comment: Yes. it just like WordPress. When a user adds in a new category, it will automatically create pages for that category so when you click on a specific link it will create views and routes on that.

Comment: if i understand, you want a separate view for each category?  If so, you should create a CategoriesController with a `show` route.  Then you can create one template `categories/show.html.erb` for that route and it will be rendered with the appropriate category.  You would need to have the route method assign category to an instance variable so it could be displayed in the template.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Still vague to me. I am a new rails 5 user. If you could take me step by step with the process that would help me a lot.

Comment: Well... it's involved.  Basically if you want to submit a form for a Blog that creates a Category, you will have to have an explicit line of code that does that in your blog controller method.  You could pass the parameter `category_name` with a name, then in your update or create method (blog controller) you could `find_or_create_by` that name.  Then, when you show that name as a link, have that route to the `show` method of the category controller.  You will need to create the controller file and add the route in your application config file.  I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use scopes here. Just use `BlogsController#show` to display posts from a given category.

Start with adding a `slug` field for the `PostCategory` (in the database). Right now you are using `title` in the URL, but it has to be changed to escaped value (without spaces, special characters, etc.).

You can probably do it with a gem, or you can use the code from [my gist](https://gist.github.com/MrShemek/58999a999ac4c8deed5593895f27b471). Just remember to adjust it to your model and fields.

Then, add a route (`routes.rb`):

```
get 'blog/:slug', to: 'blogs#show', as: :blog_category
```

Finally, in your `BlogsController`, add `show` method:

```
def show
  category = PostCategory.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
  @blogs   = Blog.where(post_category: category.id)
end
```

That's all. Of course, you can modify `show` by permitting params, adding `joins` and doing a single query for fetching blogs, but this can be done later.